# Is it possible to apply a Theme to Google Chrome when it's in "Application Mode"?

Tags: google-chrome, themes

I've applied the "brushed" theme (https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/theme_brushed.html) to my main google chrome browser windows without any problem.

However none of the "application mode" shortcuts I created pick up this theme. For example, running chrome as follows does not pick up the "brushed" theme:

chrome.exe --app=gmail.com

I want to be able to apply themes to google chrome in application mode.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment it is not possible, best thing to do would be to report the bug to google

**Edit**
I have reported this to [google](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5e20d6791490e607&hl=en) -